# Extend Java.logging for another log level?

Tags: java, logging, extending, errorlevel

I was wondering, if it is possible to extend the standard java logger (java.util.logging.Logger;) for another logger level.

The goal is, that there should show up "ERROR" instead of "SEVERE" in the log files.

Is that possible?
Or do I have to use a different logger instead (e.g. Log4j)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Andreas Vogler's version works. Create this class:

```
public class MyErrorLevel extends java.util.logging.Level 
{
    public MyErrorLevel() 
    {
        super("ERROR", 1000);
    }
}
```

To use it in your running program code, you have to do it that way:

```
logger.log(new MyErrorLevel(),"My Error number one");
```

If you need more than one errorLevel you can do it that way:

```
public class MyErrorLevel extends Level
{

public static MyErrorLevel ERROR = new MyErrorLevel ("ERROR", 950);
public static MyErrorLevel SERIOUS_ERROR = new MyErrorLevel("SERIOUS_ERROR", 980);
//...and so on...

private MyErrorLevel(String name, int value)
    {
        super (name, value);
    }

}
```

In your program code, you can use it like this:

```
logger.log(MyErrorLevel.ERROR, "my other error");
logger.log(MyErrorLevel.SERIOUS_ERROR, "my significant Error");
```

Now, if you don't want to specify your own classname (MyErrorLevel.SERIOUS_ERROR) everytime and instead you want to use 'standard-methods' (e. g. like the already existing method `logger.info("my information")`) you may think about extending the logger itself with new methods. This should (as far as my understanding goes) basically work like that:

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger
{

public MyLogger(String name, String resourceBundleName)
    {
        super(name, resourceBundleName);    
    }

public void error(String msg)
    {
        super.log(MyErrorLevel.ERROR, msg);
    }
public void error(String msg)
    {
        super.log(MyErrorLevel.SERIOUS_ERROR, msg);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to call these methods in your code like that:

```
myLogger.error("my error")
myLogger.seriousError("my serious error")
```

But I wasnt able to do it: 
I couldn't initialize my own logger with:

```
MyLogger myLogger = MyLogger.getLogger("MyModifiedLogger");
```

This doesn't compile because of type mismatch (Cannont convert from logger to MyLogger). 
I also tried:

```
MyLogger myLogger = (MyLogger)Logger.getLogger("MyModifiedLogger");
```

This results in an error message while running:
java.util.logging.Logger cannot be cast to utility.MyLogger
So somehow my extension failed. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: The problem with extending `java.util.logging.Logger` is that the standard `getLogger()` static method only knows to generate instances of `java.util.logging.Logger` - it does not know how to instantiate your `Logger` sub-class.

Comment: I'm confused. Why even extend Level as shown? java.util.Level has a constructor, public static MyErrorLevel ERROR = new Level ("ERROR", 950); should work just fine and be identical without having to create another class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print something different than the standard you could set your own formatter, see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/formatters.html

If you want to add an additional log level you can do so by subclassing java.util.logging.Level:

```
public class MyErrorLevel extends java.util.logging.Level {
    public MyErrorLevel() {
        super("ERROR", 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that latter, but I am not sure how to do it, since I am not able to open the declaration of the logging class. I tried:

`public class MyLogger extends Logger`
then I used the standard constructor. Then I wanted to declare my new method 
`public void error(String msg)`
But  what do i have to do then? Which method from the super-class can/should I use?  And I also need to extend the LoggerLevel class, i guess... 
I can't open the declaration of the super class in eclipse, since it is a compiled jar file... What is the way to go here?

Comment: Thank you, this works. I tried to show a complete solution, but in the end I ended up with another question...