# Java: getting strings from enum without having to call .toString()?

Tags: java, enums

Say I have this enum:

```
public class MyErrors {
    public enum Errors {
        BAD_FILE_PATH("Please point to a valid file");

        private final String message;

        Errors(final String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

And this call:

```
Logging.log(Level.INFO, MyErrors.Errors.BAD_FILE_PATH.toString());
```

It seems so verbose to me to have to call .toString(). Isn't there a way to just call the enum itself and have it return its string by default?

Ideally I'd like something like MyErrors.BAD_FILE_PATH --> which returns a string so it's not so verbose. Does that make any sense?

Comment: How about `"" + MyErrors.Errors.BAD_FILE_PATH`?

Comment: Sure.  _Don't use an enum._  Provide, instead, a static final String.

Comment: First time I have ever heard of calling `toString` is considered verbose

Comment: Why are you trying to use an enum for something that clearly isn't?

Comment: @Dummy actually calling toString *is* verbose, I don't remember doing so over the past few years: if you want to print an object you can simply print the object (which will implicitly call its toString method).

Comment: @alfasin but using an object as an argument in a method doesn't mean to call toString() implicitly.

Comment: @AKSW why call its toString? pass the object and let the other method figure it out.

Comment: Which is obviously not implemented in that way in the underlying logging framework...Anyways, I don't see any problem here. In the worst case, add a method `msg()` to the enum and call this, although it's still necessary to call a method.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291076/java-enum-why-use-tostring-instead-of-name

Answer (score 1):

Both of these work for me in Eclipse:

```
    LOG.info(Errors.BAD_FILE_PATH);   // Using Log4j
    System.out.println(Errors.BAD_FILE_PATH);
```

These two methods take an Object parameter.  And since are not receiving Strings, the logic in those methods must call the toString() method on the passed in object to obtain a string.

The log() method of java.util.logging.Logger does not support an Object parameter.  Instead, it is expecting a String parameter; thus, the logic in this method has no need to call toString().

What you are looking for is a new signature for the Logger that supports an Object parameter.  However, I don't know that extending the Logger is a straight forward process or advisable; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976853/extends-java-util-logging-logger-not-working).

Another option would be to use Log4j.

Comment: I'm using import java.util.logging.Logger, and using the first signature of (Level level, String message). I get "cannot resolve method 'log'" if I don't have the .toString... so full code looks like LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ErrorMessages.Errors.STARTED.toString());